# Testing constructor method that invokes async method

Tags: reactjs, angular, jestjs

I've got a component that I'm testing that I instantiate in `beforeEach` with its dependencies:

```
let fixture: MyComponent
fixture = new MyComponent(dependency1, dependency2);
```

In the component class, the constructor calls a method that returns a Promise:

```
constructor( dep1, dep2){
    this.initComponent() // returns a Promise
}
```

Naturally, the test setup test will fail:

```
test('it should get created', () => {
    expect(fixture).toBeTruth()
}
```

With the expected error of:

```
Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit
```

I tried to spy on the `initComponent()` method but that seems to fail because 1. it's private, and 2. I'm using TypeScript. Even if `async`/`await` I'm getting the error that await doesn't work in this type of expression, i.e.

```
await this.initComponent();
```

How else can I avoid this error?

Comment: Constructors can't be async, so it becomes very difficult to correctly handle problems; why not have a static method that returns a promise of a created instance? Can you give a [mre] and explain more of the context here?

Comment: Thanks. So the static method is async and it 1. creates an instance 2. calls the other async method i want.

Comment: Potentially, yes. It's hard to see how this fits together with so little information, though - you don't even show the method in question, and your class doesn't seem to use either of its dependencies.

Comment: Understood, now I see why my posts are getting downvoted and marked to close because it needs debugging details. The use of dependencies is implied and irrelevant, that's why I left them out. The only thing germane is calling an asynchronous function in the constructor. but i understand your point now. I'll def. add more details next time -- and i appreciate your help as always. thanks.

Comment: As far as I can see _nobody's_ downvoted this post. If the dependencies aren't relevant then take them out entirely, that's part of creating a MRE - we need something that fits together and we can run locally to recreate the issue.

Comment: Duly noted. Edited my comment above.